# Are regular Hadamard matrices symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-matrices

I am trying to show that a regular Hadamard matrix must have order $m^2$ for some integer $m$.

So far I have found that if $H$ is an $r$-regular Hadamard matrix of order $n$, then $HJ = rJ$ and $HH^TJ = nJ$.

Does that mean if I can prove that $H=H^T$, then it follows that $n = r^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular Hadamard matrix has all row and column sums equal, for instance
$$\pmatrix{1&-1&1&1\\1&1&-1&1\\1&1&1&-1\\-1&1&1&1}.$$

ADDED IN EDIT

In a regular Hadamard matrix, $Hu=ru$ and $H^Tu=ru$ where $u$ is the all-ones column vector and $r$ is the row/column sum. Therefore
$$HH^Tu=H(ru)=r^2u.$$
But $HH^T=nI$ by Hadamard-ness, so
$$HH^Tu=nu.$$
Therfore $n=r^2$.

Comment: Thanks, so it doesn't have to be symmetric. But still $HJ=H^TJ=rJ$,and $HH^TJ=nJ$. Do these imply that $n=r^2$?